# Using source() within parallel foreach loops

Tags: r, foreach

Here is a toy example to illustrate my problem.

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=2)

foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar%{
  i + 2
}
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 4
```

So far so good...

But if the code `i + 2` is saved in the file `addition.R` and that I call that file using `source()` then

```
> foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar%{
+   source("addition.R")
+ }
Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'i' not found"
```

Comment: Try this `source("addtition.R",local=T)` to evaluate the source in the envronment in which it's called

Comment: I find source() call in %dopar% blocks significantly slows down the computation, as the child processes have to obtain that source file through networking

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I cannot fully reproduce your toy, but I had a smiliar problem, which I was able to solve by:

```
source(file, local = TRUE)
```

which should parse the source in the local environment, i.e. recognizing i.

Answer (score 7):

The comment by NiceE and the answer by Sosel already address this; when calling `source(file)` it defaults to `source(file, local = FALSE)`, which means that the code in the file sourced is evaluating in the global environment ("user's workspace") and there is, cf. `?source`.  Note that there is no variable `i` in the global environment.  The solution is to make sure the file sourced in the environment that calls it, i.e. to use `source(file, local = TRUE)`.

## Solution:

```
library("foreach")

y <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% {
  i + 2
}
str(y)

doMC::registerDoMC(cores = 2L)
y <- foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% {
  source("addition.R", local = TRUE)
}
str(y)
```

## Example of the same problem with a `for()` loop:

The fact that `source()` is evaluated in the global environment which is different from the calling environment where `i` lives can also be illustrated using a regular for loop by running the for loop in another environment than the global, e.g. inside a function or by:

```
local({
  for(i in 1:2) {
    source("addition.R")
  }
})
```

which gives:

```
Error in eval(ei, envir) : object 'i' not found
```

Now, the reason why the above `foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% { source("addition.R") }` works with `registerDoSEQ()` *if and only if* called from the global environment, is that then the foreach iteration is evaluated in the calling environment, which is the global environment, which is the environment that `source()` uses.  However, if one used `local(foreach(i = 1:2) %dopar% { ... })` also this fails analoguously to the above `local(for(i in 1:2) { ... })` call.

In conclusion: nothing magic happens, but to understand it is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved the problem by converting the source("addition.R") to a function and simply passing the variables into it. I don't know why but the suggested solutions based on `source(file, local = TRUE)` does not work.

Comment: That `source("addition.R", local = TRUE)` would not work for you does not make sense to me. Can you replicate the error with the reproducible example I adopted from your OP?  Or are you refering to a more complex R script?  If the latter, there can be millions of reasons.  Also, what setup / `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I am talking about the exact mentioned script and the exact error.

Comment: This is really weird.  Do you get the error also in that `local({ for(i in 1:12) ... })` example?  If so, that would rule out foreach etc.   Importantly, what's your `sessionInfo()` after you get the error?  I suspect there's something in your setup causing this difference.  Running R in the terminal, or in a GUI (e.g RStudio)?