# Sourcing an .R file leading to Error in eval(ei, envir):

Tags: r

I have a problem with sourcing an .R file, which leads to the Error in eval(ei, envir):. The whole code works like usual when I run it manually in RStudio without sourcing it.

Comment: Are you using non ASC symbols in this script, R really can get buggy when I try to use portuguese special characters

Comment: I don't think I am. Is there any way I can check for it?

Comment: There might be something in your RStudio workspace that you don't realize your script relies on.  Clear your Rstudio workspace and see if the script can be sourced.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers I guess I wasn't clear. When I try to source my .R file in terminal or new RStudio session, the code doesn't work. However, when I each line of the script separately in a fresh RStudio session, everything works fine without this error.

Comment: Gotcha. Tough to help without seeing the script. You could try `options(error=recover)` to see where exactly in the script the problem arises.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46923401/12601988

I think I get something similar to what @HenrikB mentioned here under his example. I'm running a for() loop in my script that I'm trying to source and I get this error "Error in eval(ei, envir)".

Answer (score 1):

**Local = T**
To expound on the answers in your link, if you have a script, `toSource.R` that contains the following:

```
print(x)
```

Then in another script, something like this won't work because the script, `toSource.R` will be evaluated in the global environment, not `PrintX`'s internal environment:

```
printX <- function() {
  x <- 2
  source('toSource.R')
}
## yields "Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found "
printX()
```

This will work since `x` is now in the global environment:

```
x <- 2
printX()
```

This will also work since source is now instructed to use the calling environment, which is the internal environment of `PrintX`:

```
printX <- function() {
  x <- 2
  source('toSource.R', local =T)
}

printX()
```